# Is it possible for a RNG skewed by seed?

Tags: random

As the question asks, Is it possible for a badly programmed Pseudo RNG to be skewed by the seed used to generate the random number? If yes, what are the common mistakes that causes this to happen?

Comment: Simply use a good PRNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few examples:

- https://banu.com/blog/42/openbsd-bug-in-the-random-function/
- the old seeding procedure used by Mersenne Twister (http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/MT2002/emt19937ar.html links to a clear explanation)
- the old super duper (can't find the link atm) was supposed to have period ~2^64, but some seeds gave it period ~2^5x

Also, even if it's not really a bug, many, many generators initialize themselves with something like

`if seed == 0:
    # comment explaining that zero is bad
    seed = nonzero`

or

`// Due to (reasons) we only really allow seeds in [0,M)
seed = seed % M`

meaning that there will be at least two seeds giving identical results.
Examples: xorgens (zero=>nonzero), java's Random (seed is 64 bits, internal state is 48 bits...), go's math/rand (it does both things, see the first lines of the Seed() method at https://golang.org/src/math/rand/rng.go)

Comment: I don't really understand some of the examples. Could I just ask a direct question? For example, if I would do a lottery and the PRNG is initialised with the username of the user as the seed, would it be possible for him to enter a username that will skew the lottery generation in his favour? Like he's able to generate more higher numbers than lower numbers.

Comment: If there's any example you'd like to see explained better, just ask... A user who knows the seed can just run the PRNG himself and see what numbers come out; my answer assumed you only need a statistical PRNG, if you have a human adversary you'll need a CSPRNG with unpredictable seed (from /dev/urandom, or getrandom()/getentropy()/RtlGenRandom(), or whatever it's called on your system, or on the library you're using). Anything else, and you'll end up with "wow, my users are really creative!"